# NetBeans : JUnit no tests executed

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

So I'm getting this persistent error using netbeans. I've got a LinkedList class which I am testing via a JUnit test, which I created by clicking on LinkedList.java: Tools -> Create/Update Tests and this LinkedListTest.java class is now located in test packages.
My LinkedList.java file works correctly when tested in a file with a main method.

```
public class LinkedListTest {    

@Test
public void testAddFirst() {

    LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
    Country c1 = new Country("Australia");

    linkedList.addFirst(c1);
    assertEquals("Australias", linkedList.getValue(0)); // Should fail a test

} // default test methods beneath
```

All my imports check out. JUnit 5.3.1 and I had to download apiguardian1.1.0.jar from MVN repository to clear an error for:

```
reason: class file for org.apiguardian.api.API$Status not found
```

I right-click in this file and select Test File, or use Ctrl+F6, I've selected Test File from the original LinkedList file, I've even used Alt+F6 which tests the whole project. Yet I'm met with 'No tests executed.', an empty Test Results window, and no Notifications. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help

Edit: I just switched from netbeans to eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure that you added a correct `jUnit5` runner?

Comment: I've checked a few NetBeans resources with no luck. Just changed the title to be more specific. Also I'm currently looking at runners and I have none, when I try to import the @RunWith annotation I can't. I'll try searching more

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: have you tried deleting the NetBeans cache? And are tests executed if you compile your project on the command line?

Answer (score -1):

You forget to extend `Runner` with class --

use like below with class -

```
public class LinkedListTest extends Runner {    

}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: JUnit5 shouldn't need to specify a runner either way right? This didn't work btw